# Joda: get local milliseconds of specific timezone

Tags: java

I never would believe that this could amount to being such a hassle. I am trying to make a clock that always displays the local time in specific timezones.

My laptop is currently set in GMT0 timezone (UK).

I want to get the milliseconds of the timezone "Europe/Stockholm".

So let's say it's 17:00 here in the UK I would like to get the milliseconds corresponding to 18:00 which would be the Swedish time.

Comment: It would be the same amount of milliseconds.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sweden is one hour ahead so why isn't Swedens milliseconds 60*60*1000 more?

Comment: Because the "milliseconds time" is since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 **UTC** - note, it's always since this specific time in UTC, it is not dependent on any local timezone.

Comment: @Jesper Ah so no matter what locale you have on the computer, new Date() will always return UTC from 1970?

Comment: Yes, `java.util.Date.getTime()` always returns milliseconds since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 UTC, no matter what your system timezone is.

Comment: @Jesper I feel overwhelmed that I now know this haha. I understand the whole thing now.

Answer (score 1):

The time in milliseconds as used by Date is independent of the time zone. Only when you print (or parse) a time, you use a DateFormat that is localized, so it ensures you get the time in the specific timezone.

Answer (score 1):

When time is represented as milliseconds (or seconds or nanoseconds, etc), that is almost always milliseconds since some [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Computing). In the case of [unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()), this is midnight Jan 1, 1970 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Time zones are generally arranged as a round number of hours relative to UTC. In certain time zones it's not a round hour but 30 minutes, 15 minutes or 45 minutes from a round hour.

Nevertheless, for any time unit below a minute, all those time zones match UTC exactly.

Therefore, whatever the current second or millisecond is in Sweden, it is the same as it is, for example, in Nepal, whose time zone is 5:45 minutes from UTC.

When you work with an object that allows you to retrieve the separate fields of the given time, the milliseconds field will usually reflect just the number of milliseconds since the beginning of the current second, not the number of milliseconds since midnight. Therefore it will never be more than 999, and it will be the same the world over.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answers here and discovering another route, this is what finally worked for me.

```
DateTime curDateTime = new DateTime();
int offset = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Stockholm").getOffset(curDateTime.getMillis());
long milli = (curDateTime.getMillis()+offset);
```

Comment: Define "worked". What are you going to do with the `milli` value calculated? Because it no longer represents a (meaningful) absolute point in time.

Comment: @BrettOkken If you can think of any other way to get the same effect be my guest! As my original question states, I would like to get the milliseconds of the local time in Sweden to do calculations (these calculations you do not have to know about).